# JavaScript событие при нажатии и удерживании клавиши

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ли возможность переопределить для input поля событие, когда пользователь нажимает и держит кнопку клавиатуры ?

Есть текстовое поле с `id="char"` , нужно как-то запретить нажатие и удержание клавиши. Но повторяющеися символы можно в любом количестве.

Comment: Если запретить удержание по причине только лишь повторяющихся символов - то используйте считывание в момент keyup. Игнорируя keypress и keydown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var value = '';

$('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (value === e.key) {
    console.log('SAME');
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  value = e.key;
});
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  value = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

Заводим переменную, в которую пишем клавишу что мы нажали. Если клавиша зажата (повторный вызов keypress/keydown без вызова keyup), то блокируем. Как оказалось, лучше вешаеть событие на keypress т.к. он не реагирует на специальные символы

" Любые буквы, цифры генерируют keypress. Управляющие клавиши, такие как Ctrl, Shift, F1, F2… – keypress не генерируют." [тык](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events)

Comment: что за _window.preventAction_?

Comment: @Grundy согласен - поправил на e. Спасибо!

Comment: а `e.preventAction` - это что?

Comment: @Grundy насколько мне известно, именно этот флаг меняется при e.preventDefault(). Т.е. при значении false, поведение по умолчанию вновь активно. И как оказалось он не нужен =_=. Поправил ответ. Совет взял отсюда http://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/32544-otmena-preventdefault-ili-vozobnovlenie-sobytiya-nazhatiya-na-klavishu-klaviatury.html

Comment: Такого флага не существует, это раз, по своей же ссылке посмотри _зачем_ они используют поле в объекте window. В твоем случае это не нужно

Comment: @Grundy вы абсолютно правы - я что-то просмотрел этот момент. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А хороший способ. У меня сначала другая идея возникла...